# Does MTOM require a messageContract in WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, mtom

Is there any way use datacontracts while using Mtom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's [nothing preventing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx) you from using data contracts with MTOM.

Answer (score 0):

no, but the only thing in the body of the message must be the file.
if you have more than one parameter in the method, you must use a message contract because you have to specify where the things will go, on the header or on the body. This way you can put only the file in the body.